# Photo Sphere Viewer plugin Stop autorotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Photo sphere plugin in my website. I want to stop auto rotation/move the following mentioned slider. Currently the photo rotating from left to right after few seconds.

http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/

Comment: Share you code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing the script, use the following parameter:

time_anim: false

All settings are described in the [table](http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/#installation)